# What type of capacitor do i need for this delay?

Tags: led, capacitor, relay, timer, rgb

I installed a set of LED RGB foot-well lights on my truck.

When they turned on, they have a small half second glitch before staying constant.

I believe that this is because the LED RGB controller needs to power up and that the initial power lights up the LED for a second before staying constant.

I first thought that I could just switch the LED's instead of the module itself, so it always has power.  However, my module is on the common position of a three position switch. One position is constant power, and the other is on a relay that activates when my door is unlocked or opened (on BCM).

So I need a way to delay the LED's for half a second so the box can power up and avoid the glitch.

I was thinking of a timer relay but I would rather build my own device and save money.

Perhaps an inline capacitor would work? How would I do this, and what capacitor would I need?

Comment: I'm not sure how a capacitor would help with this, can you explain your idea better?  Also, you will be more likely to get help here if you put just a bit more effort into grammar and formatting.  Capitalize your "I"s, don't replace "you're" with "ur", use paragraphs, etc.  Finally, a link to a datasheet for your LED controller would really help you get answers.

Comment: If you know how to place a retarded relay to do the job you very likely know where to connect a sturdy mosfet  (=its drain and source) to do the same job as the contact of the relay would do. Then you can let a charging RC circuit turn the mosfet  ON. We cannot draw a schematic nor select parts because we know nothing of the actual construction of your existing circuit. BTW 1) if you planned to let a capacitor to sink everything what's offered to the leds you have planned a momentary short circuit and maybe the funerals of your system 2) place hobby quality electronics to a truck=beg troubles.

Comment: _"I know what ur thinking i could just switch the leds instead of the module"_ - no, I'm thinking why do you need RGB footwell lights in a truck?

Comment: Well a time delay relay works through a capacitor right? How can i rig a capacitor in line to absorb the initial power up of the rgb controlled. Just need a split second delay between the module and my led strips.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Silence peasant!

Comment: The way I read your question, you want to use a capacitor to avoid voltage spikes/smooth out ripple on start up, is that right? If so I'd just use an 100uF electrolytic capacitor between the voltage and ground.

Answer (score 0):

to blank tyhr leds during startup you could use a relay with a capacitor to interrupt the common line of the LED strips. something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJz2ii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

about 1000uF would be a good starting point,